# Meteor app doesn't appear in browser after deployment with mup

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I'm facing strange issue - I deployed my Meteor app with mup ( followed this instruction: https://www.vultr.com/docs/deploy-a-meteor-application-on-ubuntu ). Everything went successfully (see screenshot).

[image: issue]

However the content doesn't appear when I try to access it via browser (I type IP-address).

As a server I use apache2 on Ubuntu 15.04, and mup.json as following:

```
{
// Server authentication info
"servers": [
{
  "host": "IP_ADDRESS",
  "username": "developer"
  //"password": "password"
  // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
  //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
}
],

// Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
"setupMongo": false,

// WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
"setupNode": true,

// WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
"nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

// Install PhantomJS in the server
"setupPhantom": true,

// Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server. 
// Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
"enableUploadProgressBar": true,

// Application name (No spaces)
"appName": "meteor",

// Location of app (local directory)
"app": "~/app",

// Configure environment
"env": {
"PORT": 80,
"UPSTART_UID": "meteoruser",
"ROOT_URL": "http://IP_ADDRESS",//and I also tried http://localhost
//"MONGO_URL": "",
"METEOR_ENV": "production"
},

// Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
// before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
"deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

UPD: I made a better research and found a great tutorial - https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/apache/oss/vivid/deploy_app.html . So, if anyone else curious about how to deploy Meteor app, please have a look :)

Comment: Are you using an external server for your mongodb?

Comment: That tutorial seems a little incomplete to me. I've written one that may be more helpful (goo.gl/uQSNX9), but I'm not sure the deployment is your issue. It looks like spacebars wasn't fully installed. What happened when you ran `mup setup`?